# When or where are Psalms not sung in Judaism?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

I was listening to a Jewish oration and mention was made of not saying Psalms between (something said in Hebrew).  Not knowing Hebrew I was not sure what was being spoken of.  Are there times or places, according to your traditions, that you are not supposed to read/sing/pray the Psalms.

Comment: Most of our time is in fact not spent singing Psalms. Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: IT sounded like there was a time you are not supposed to sing them according to your tradition.

Comment: There are opinions that hold that one should not recite psalms between nightfall and midnight. Perhaps that is what was being referenced. See here: http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2539 and here: http://dinonline.org/2010/07/25/tehillim-at-night/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At night (until midnight) is one of them see

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2539

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting.  Do I understand correctly that it is in regard to placing priority on Torah at those times?  Why those specific days?

Comment: @Sarah see http://dinonline.org/2010/07/25/tehillim-at-night/ might be more clear, all day exept shabos and yom tov (and the day that you are obligated to say anyway)